# C struct representation in Swift

Tags: objective-c, c, swift

Think in C: I have memory buffer (flat 3D) with millions of `Object` structs and I want to have re-calculated neighbours :

```
typedef struct Object {
    vector_int3 coords;
    struct Object *neighbours[6]; // Neighbouring objects in 6 directions
    int prop1;
} Object;
```

to be able later access for example `chunk->neighbours[TOP]->prop1;`

I'm trying to achieve same thing with Swift, I tried:

```
struct Object {
    var coords: vector_int3
    // IMO this is wrong, because it allocates new heap buffer for 6 pointers
    var neighbours = UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>.allocate(capacity: 6)
    var prop1: Int
    ...
}
```

I just want to have buffer of 6 pointers to `Object` in Swift to be able to access it by index. What would be closest Swift implementation of mentioned C struct? And no, it's not premature optimisation.

Comment: "flat 3D" is kinda.. oxymoron.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I meant not int buf[10][10][10] but buf[1000]. Just matter of representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to the C struct would look like

```
struct Object {
    var coords: vector_int3
    var neighbours: (UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>)
    var prop1: Int
    ...
}
```

And yes, it's quite unwieldy.

Comment: Thought about it (tuples). But is this only option?

Comment: If you want all your pointers to be inline instead of stored in a separate heap allocation, then either this, or have 6 different properties (e.g. `var neighbor0: UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>; var neighbor1: UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>; …`.

Comment: Also depending on your use case you may actually want optional pointers (e.g. `UnsafeMutablePointer<Chunk>?`).

Comment: You can always just use an object. (: (I did that to make a node tree.)